# border-image-slice swaps horizontal and vertical params in Chrome and FireFox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, border-image

I am trying to make only horizontal(/vertical) borders with this code:

```
.test {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(to bottom, hsl(0, 0%, 97%), hsl(19, 0%, 75%), hsl(0, 0%, 97%));
   border-image-slice: 100% 1%;
}
```

It works. But only in Chrome. [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCl7i.png)

In Firefox lines swap direction. They become vertical:
[FF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apdc2.png)

If I change "border-image-slice: 100% 1%;"  to "border-image-slice: 1% 100%;" browsers change effects too.

Maybe someone deal with it? Maybe i missed something? Maybe exists cross browser solution.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS in your question is not the entire CSS you used to produce the output in CodePen. It would be useful if you provided a link to it in future. With the following, I cannot reproduce the issue. I get the two horizontal sides in both browsers, so I suspect the issue lies with the other CSS:

**HTML**

```
<div class="repeating-linear">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.repeating-linear {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(to bottom, hsl(0, 0%, 97%), 
        hsl(19, 0%, 75%), hsl(0, 0%, 97%));
    border-image-slice: 100% 1%;
}
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/0j745Lzm/1/